# can i use a console application that execute powershell script as a custom action

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, installation

In my solution, I have a windows service and WPF application to mange this service 
and a console application that executes Powershell script files and also, an installer project.

In my installer project, I want to add a custom action (the console app) that execute the Powershell functions.

When I try to install, I get an error.

**My Question is:**  can I use a console application that executes powershell script as a custom action?

I'm using visual studio 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: To be clear: From a Windows Installer you call a console application from a Custom Action and you want that console application to execute powershell functions? Also please explain a bit more what you already tried (code?) and what the error was

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that PowerShell is not installed by default on Windows XP and Windows Vista?  If that is OK, the next hurdle is the default execution policy does not allow script execution. You can get around that by using the powershell.exe parameter `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`.  However that parameter is not available in PowerShell 1.0 IIRC.

Personally, I'd be a bit wary about relying on PowerShell for a custom action but if you know the environment this is installing into (corp/IT app) then go for it.  :-)